# Firefox onKeyUp value missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, missing-data, keyup

Very simply, the below code will alert the correct value in every browser I have tried other than Firefox (I am using the latest v24). The problem has something to do with the "enter" button or something. When I press enter, and try to alert the value first thing, I don't get any value returned. As if the value just disappears.

```
var companyInput = $('input').attr('type', 'text');
companyInput.on('keyup', function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var keycode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.keyChar;
    if (keycode == 13) {
        alert(value)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2aybA

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: don't use "value" as a variable

Comment: Are you asking about mobile or desktop Firefox? I think the fiddle works OK on my desktop (release: v24), but it's hard to tell because pressing enter tries to submit. For mobile, be aware of [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=763201)

Comment: @Jeremy: This is the desktop version of FF that I'm having the problem in.

Comment: @Rituraj: I always tend to use "value" as a variable. Why not?

Comment: @Justin sorry to say it might just be you. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38Rtg/1/) indicates both e.which and e.keyCode both work fine for me. (Using plain JS, not jQuery)